# Creating dependent drop down list using two columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a dependent drop down list using excel. I have two columns
CODE and CITY. Sample data is as below.

```
CODE CITY
1    MUMBAI
2    DELHI
3    MUMBAI
3    DELHI
3    CALCUTTA
4    GURGUAM
5    NAVI MUMBAI
6    NAVI MUMBAI
6    CHENNAI
6    BANGALORE
```

The excel file has 18k such repeated CODE with unique cities.

As of now, below steps I have performed,

```
1. I have created a list of CODE using validation in one cell.

2. I have selected both the columns and created the name manager using Name Manager in formulas.

3. Next to the CODE list I have created a list and inside the source I have put the formula =indirect(A2)
```

The new list is blank.

I am expecting the list of cities in the city list based on the input of CODE.

Requesting your assistance.

Comment: Did you do a **[search](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)**?

Comment: Thank @Sami, I have read this article but it could not solve my problem. Article has only three values for list to make. I have 18k values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

G5 = code you're interested in

Codes = Named range of city codes

C5 = first city in list

Then put the below formula into the data valiation > list > source:
=OFFSET($C$5,MATCH(G5,Codes,0)-1,,COUNTIF(Codes,G5))